how to setup connection between 2 servers with NIC 10GB [Hetzner]
I ordered 2 servers with NIC 10GB on hetzner but I can't see their IP LAN
This is my netplan configuration:
vim /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
### Hetzner Online GmbH installimage
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp41s0:
      mtu: 1400
      addresses:
        - <publicIPv4>/32
        - <publicIPv6>/64
        - 192.168.1.10/24
      routes:
        - on-link: true
          to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 142.132.153.193
        - to: default
          via: fe80::1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 185.12.64.2
          - 2a01:4ff:ff00::add:1
          - 185.12.64.1
          - 2a01:4ff:ff00::add:2

root@Ubuntu-2404-noble-amd64-base ~ # lspci | egrep -i 'eth|wifi|wireless'
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)
29:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)

Please help me to debug the problem.
